# Class not found in C:\wamp\www\system\core\Loader.php on line 303

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

OK, I am new to PHP so I plead you to have understanding. 
I have made my new application, however I can't figure out why is it complaining about. I get very odd and strange error

```
    db->query($sql); 
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
       $row = $query->row(); 
       foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
          $this->$key = $val; 
       } 
       return $row; 
    } 
    return null; 
} 

function getUser($info=NULL, $active=NULL) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE 1 = 1 "; 
    if (!is_null($info)) { 
        if (empty($info->username) || empty($info->password)) { 
            return null; 
        } 
        if (!empty($info->username)) { 
            $sql .= " AND (username = '{$info->username}' OR email = '{$info->username}' OR id = '{$info->username}') ";
        }
        if (!empty($info->password)) { 
            $sql .= " AND password = '".md5($info->password)."' ";
        } 
    }
    if (!empty($active)) { 
        $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}' "; 
    }
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
        $row = $query->row(); 
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) { 
            $this->$key = $val; 
        } 
        return $row; 
    } 
    return null; 
}

function getUsers($active=NULL) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE 1 = 1"; 
    if (!empty($active)) { 
        $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}'"; 
    }
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    return $query->result(); 
}

function isUserExist($username=NULL, $active=NULL) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE 1 = 1 "; 
    if (!empty($username)) { 
        $sql .= " AND username = '{$username}' "; 
    } 
    if (!empty($active)) { 
        $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}' "; 
    } 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0); 
} 

function getUserByEmail($email, $active=NULL) { 
    if (empty($email)) { return null; } 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE email = '{$email}' "; 
    if (!empty($active)) { 
        $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}' "; 
    } 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
        $row = $query->row(); 
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) { 
            $this->$key = $val; 
        } 
        return $row; 
     } 
     return null; 
} 

function getSocialUser($uid=NULL, $provider,$email=NULL, $active=NULL) {
    if (empty($provider)) { return null; } 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE 1 = 1 "; 
    if (!empty($uid)) { $sql .= " AND uid = '{$uid}' "; } 
    if (!empty($email)) { $sql .= " AND email = '{$email}' "; } 
    $sql .= " AND provider='{$provider}'"; 
    if (!empty($active)) { $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}' "; } 
        $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
            $row = $query->row(); 
            foreach ($row as $key => $val) { 
                $this->$key = $val; 
            } 
            return $row; 
         } 
     return null; 
}

function uuid() { 
    return strtoupper(substr(dechex(time()).dechex(mt_rand(1,65535)), 0, 6)); 
} 

function add($data) { 
    return $this->db->insert("tv_user", $data); 
} 

function update($data, $where) { 
    return $this->db->update("tv_user", $data, $where); 
}

function delete($where) { 
    return $this->db->delete("tv_user", $where); 
}

function login($username, $password) { 
    if (empty($username) || empty($password)) { 
        return FALSE; 
    }
    $password = md5($password); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}' AND active=1"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
        $user = $query->row(); 
        $user_data = array(); 
        foreach($user as $key => $val){ 
            $user_data[$key] = $val; 
        } 
        $user_data["login"] = TRUE; 
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $user_data); 
        if ($user->user_type == USR_ROOT) { 
            $this->session->set_userdata('root_addmin_logged_in', TRUE); 
            $this->session->set_userdata('addmin_logged_in', TRUE); 
        } else 
            if (in_array($user->user_type,array(USR_ADMIN, 
                                                USR_MODERATOR, 
                                                USR_TOUR, 
                                                USR_HOTEL, 
                                                USR_FLIGHT, 
                                                USR_VISA)
                )) 
             { 
                  $this->session->set_userdata('root_addmin_logged_in', FALSE); 
                  $this->session->set_userdata('addmin_logged_in', TRUE);
             } else { 
                  $this->session->set_userdata('root_addmin_logged_in', FALSE); 
                  $this->session->set_userdata('addmin_logged_in', FALSE); 
             } 
             $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
             $this->session->set_userdata('logged_user', $user); 
             return TRUE; 
         } 
         return FALSE; 
     } 

     function logout() { $this->session->sess_destroy(); } 

      function verify_reset_password_code($email, $code) { 
          if (empty($email) || empty($code)) { 
              return FALSE; 
          } 
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE email = '{$email}' "; 
          $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
          if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
              $row = $query->row(); 
              return ($code == md5(SITE_NAME.$row->fullname))? TRUE : FALSE; 
          } else { 
              return FALSE; 
          } 
      }
 } 
?>
```

which is interpreted as

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'M_user' not found in C:\wamp\www\system\core\Loader.php on line 303
```

[image]

I am not very good in this since I am new. I have to say that I am running my application under WAMP.It may be something trivial, but I don't get it.

I have even included all modules in my autoload.php file as following:

```
$autoload['model'] = array(
'm_user',
'm_user_online',
'm_content_category',
'm_content',
'm_nation',
'm_mail',
'm_message',
'm_feedback',
'm_photo',
'm_tour',
'm_tour_rate',
'm_tour_departure',
'm_tour_departure_rate',
'm_tour_itinerary',
'm_tour_category',
'm_tour_activity',
'm_tour_destination',
'm_tour_tripnote',
'm_tour_request',
'm_visa',
'm_visa_tips',
'm_question',
'm_hotel',
'm_room',
'm_room_rate',
'm_album_category',
'm_album',
'm_tour_option_category'
```

);

Part of the code where it gets mentioned:

```
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Model Loader
 *
 * This function lets users load and instantiate models.
 *
 * @param   string  the name of the class
 * @param   string  name for the model
 * @param   bool    database connection
 * @return  void
 */
public function model($model, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE)
{
    if (is_array($model))
    {
        foreach ($model as $babe)
        {
            $this->model($babe);
        }
        return;
    }

    if ($model == '')
    {
        return;
    }

    $path = '';

    // Is the model in a sub-folder? If so, parse out the filename and path.
    if (($last_slash = strrpos($model, '/')) !== FALSE)
    {
        // The path is in front of the last slash
        $path = substr($model, 0, $last_slash + 1);

        // And the model name behind it
        $model = substr($model, $last_slash + 1);
    }

    if ($name == '')
    {
        $name = $model;
    }

    if (in_array($name, $this->_ci_models, TRUE))
    {
        return;
    }

    $CI =& get_instance();
    if (isset($CI->$name))
    {
        show_error('The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: '.$name);
    }

    $model = strtolower($model);

    foreach ($this->_ci_model_paths as $mod_path)
    {
        if ( ! file_exists($mod_path.'models/'.$path.$model.'.php'))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if ($db_conn !== FALSE AND ! class_exists('CI_DB'))
        {
            if ($db_conn === TRUE)
            {
                $db_conn = '';
            }

            $CI->load->database($db_conn, FALSE, TRUE);
        }

        if ( ! class_exists('CI_Model'))
        {
            load_class('Model', 'core');
        }

        require_once($mod_path.'models/'.$path.$model.'.php');

        $model = ucfirst($model);

        $CI->$name = new $model();

        $this->_ci_models[] = $name;
        return;
    }

    // couldn't find the model
    show_error('Unable to locate the model you have specified: '.$model);
}
```

This is my m_user.php class:

```
<?
      class M_User extends CI_Model
      {
       function load($id)
        {
        $sql   = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE id = '{$id}' ";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
            return $row;
        }
        return null;
    }

    function getUser($info=NULL, $active=NULL)
    {
        $sql   = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE 1 = 1 ";
        if (!is_null($info)) {
            if (empty($info->username) || empty($info->password)) {
                return null;
            }
            if (!empty($info->username)) {
                $sql .= " AND (username = '{$info->username}' OR email = '{$info->username}' OR id = '{$info->username}') ";
            }
            if (!empty($info->password)) {
                $sql .= " AND password = '".md5($info->password)."' ";
            }
        }

        if (!empty($active)) {
            $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}' ";
        }

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
            return $row;
        }
        return null;
    }

    function getUsers($active=NULL)
    {
        $sql   = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE 1 = 1";
        if (!empty($active)) {
            $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}'";
        }

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }

    function isUserExist($username=NULL, $active=NULL)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE 1 = 1 ";
        if (!empty($username)) {
            $sql .= " AND username = '{$username}' ";
        }

        if (!empty($active)) {
            $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}' ";
        }

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return ($query->num_rows() > 0);
    }

    function getUserByEmail($email, $active=NULL)
    {
        if (empty($email)) {
            return null;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE email = '{$email}' ";

        if (!empty($active)) {
            $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}' ";
        }

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
            return $row;
        }
        return null;
    }

    function getSocialUser($uid=NULL, $provider,$email=NULL, $active=NULL)
    {
        if (empty($provider)) {
            return null;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE 1 = 1 ";
        if (!empty($uid)) {
            $sql .= " AND uid = '{$uid}' ";
        }

        if (!empty($email)) {
            $sql .= " AND email = '{$email}' ";
        }

        $sql .= " AND provider='{$provider}'";

        if (!empty($active)) {
            $sql .= " AND active = '{$active}' ";
        }

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
            return $row;
        }
        return null;
    }

    function uuid()
    {
        return strtoupper(substr(dechex(time()).dechex(mt_rand(1,65535)), 0, 6));
    }

    function add($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert("tv_user", $data);
    }

    function update($data, $where)
    {
        return $this->db->update("tv_user", $data, $where);
    }

    function delete($where)
    {
        return $this->db->delete("tv_user", $where);
    }

    function login($username, $password)
    {
        if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $password = md5($password);
        $sql      = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}' AND active=1";
        $query    = $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            $user = $query->row();
            $user_data = array();

            foreach($user as $key => $val){
                $user_data[$key] = $val;
            }

            $user_data["login"] = TRUE;
            $this->session->set_userdata('user', $user_data);

            if ($user->user_type == USR_ROOT) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('root_addmin_logged_in', TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('addmin_logged_in', TRUE);
            }
            else if (in_array($user->user_type, array(USR_ADMIN,USR_MODERATOR,USR_TOUR,USR_HOTEL,USR_FLIGHT,USR_VISA))) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('root_addmin_logged_in', FALSE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('addmin_logged_in', TRUE);
            }
            else {
                $this->session->set_userdata('root_addmin_logged_in', FALSE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('addmin_logged_in', FALSE);
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_user', $user);

            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
    }

    function verify_reset_password_code($email, $code)
    {
        if (empty($email) || empty($code)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tv_user WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            return ($code == md5(SITE_NAME.$row->fullname))? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code seems some error in it. Please post working code again. and make sure to follow question posting rules of SO. [Stackoverflow Formatting Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I am not quite sure what to post?

Comment: Two things: 1. Post the part of code where `M_user`is mentioned, as that is causing your error. 2. Format your code to be readable - new lines and indentation is a must if you want to read anything at all.

Comment: It's mentioned in Loader.php. I have posted part of the code where it gets mentioned. @IvanJovovic

Comment: I meant: post definition of `M_user` and places where it is invoked. It should be all your custom code, not CI core classes.

Comment: OK, here is my code. I am invoking it almost everywhere. @IvanJovovic

Comment: The first piece of code (the one with no carriage returns!) does not start with `<?php` and so is being rendered in your application as HTML instead.

Comment: Oh my dear God! I didn't even notice it. I was going through the code LINE by LINE and I didn't even notice that. I am getting definetly old! @halfer

Comment: Ha! no worries, it happens to everyone. Does it really not have any returns in it, in your editor? If so, that needs sorting out quickly - it's pretty unreadable.

Comment: Please, mark it as an answer, cause this is valuable resource if someone gets stuck like I was, and error was a bit misleading. I have never faced that issue before.

Comment: Yes, a bit vague, but I will format it. :-) Thanks, @halfer

Comment: Other notes: your first and last files may have SQL injection vulnerabilities. If this is the case, then your logon system may be trivially bypassable. Also, don't use MD5 for hashing passwords, especially unsalted. Use `password_hash` instead.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: please be careful with editing! My edits have been overwritten twice by yours now - did you not get the JavaScript warning? If you get that, you need to back out, refresh and retry.

Comment: @halfer Editing that block of code was almost a lifetime's work. Sorry but having spent 10+ minutes doing it I was not going to back out in case the other editor had done something trivial. It accepted my edit over yours as mine contained the most changes, So I guess I had completed more than you, so it seems fair that it threw yours away and kept mine. But for what its worth **Sorry**

Comment: @RiggsFolly: if it happens, copy to clipboard, examine edit and reapply as necessary. But no worries, it's been solved now anyway `:-)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

And restart your Apache server.

Comment: Better never to use the short open tag then your code will always get parsed!!

Comment: Problem is he's using some lib that is written in short tag.

Comment: Yes, so the solution is to NOT USE `<?` then the code will be transportable to **any server**

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments:

Your first chunk of PHP is appearing in your HTML view - good idea to include a screenshot! That would indicate that it is not being parsed as PHP, and instead is being parse as HTML, so I would check to see if a `<?php` appears at the start.